# Wrap and style a button in a div element using pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to wrap the following button inside a div so I can center it:

```
<button>Bottom</button>
```

This is what I tried:

```
var dv = document.createElement('div');
dv.style.textAlign= 'center';

document.getElement('button').parentNode.appendChild(dv);
```

You can see the [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/nuno/pcpfqapc/1/)

How can I do this without JQuery or other frameworks?

Comment: What's wrong with `button { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }`? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pcpfqapc/2/)

Comment: The HTML is generated by a component I don't want to change

Comment: Well you could use a specific selector and add this declaration into your stylesheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
  var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
  var dv = document.createElement('div');
  dv.style.textAlign= 'center';
  btn.parentNode.insertBefore(dv,btn);
  dv.appendChild(btn);
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/pcpfqapc/5/)

Comment: This may change the position of the button (its order in its parent node)

Answer (score 0):

Use [getElementsByTagName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp) instead of *getElement*

```
var dv = document.createElement('div');
dv.style.textAlign= 'center';
document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].parentNode.appendChild(dv);
dv.appendChild(document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0]);
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/pcpfqapc/4/)

Comment: Exactly sames as @TJ's answer

Comment: @ABFORCE take a brief look my answer is different from TJ's